# Evento ratón por encima de botón en jQuery

Tags: jquery

**Quiero que al pasar el ratón por encima del botón "Reservar" cambie el texto del botón a "Loguéate".**

```
<input type='submit' name='reservar' id='reservar' value='Reservar'/>



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.reservar').hover(function(){
        $(this).text("Reservar");
    }, function() {
        $(this).text("Logueate");
    });
});
```

Comment: en el código de jquery cambia  `'.reservar'` por `'#reservar'`

Comment: Tampoco me funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te dejo la solución, el problema es el selector, debe ser `#reservar`. Además, para cambiar el texto de un input debe ser en su atributo `value`, por lo tanto, con la función `text()` no funciona:

```js
    $('#reservar').hover(function(){
        $(this).val("Logueate");
    }, function() {
        $(this).val("Reservar");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='submit' name='reservar' id='reservar' value='Reservar'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar eventos `hover` para realizar el cambio de texto como en el siguiente ejemplo .

```css
div#line1 span#a {
  display: inline;
}

div#line1:hover span#a {
  display: none;
}

div#line1 span#b {
  display: none;
}

div#line1:hover span#b {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="line1">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="a">this is sick</span><span id="b">this is awesome</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

o con jQuery realizalo de la siguiente forma.

**.html**

```
<a class="btn" href="#">
     <img src="#" alt=""/>
    <span>Replace me</span> please
</a>
```

**.css**

```
$('.btn').hover(function(){
    $(this).text("I'm replaced!");
}, function() {
    $(this).text("Replace me please");
});
```

Comment: Tu código es muy completo y válido, ¿pero con jQuery, lo que estuve intentando...?

Comment: checa el codigo de este ejemplo o el codigo jquery que te puse abajo del primer ejemplo.  http://jsfiddle.net/3JDZs/

Comment: He intentado tu código pero no me funciona. Lo he adaptado a lo siguiente. Mira la pregunta editada, ¿dónde tengo el error?

Comment: ¿A qué se debe mi error?